# VSCode disable Automatic Keyboard Navigation

Tags: visual-studio-code

I used to delete files in the VSCode file explorer by pressing the <kbd>Delete</kbd> button. Since today, when I press <kbd>Delete</kbd>, VSCode wants to filter files with the string "Delete".

[image: Functionality]

How can I delete files with the <kbd>Delete</kbd> button again?

My keyboard shortcuts:
[image: Keyboard shortcuts]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out that this behaviour comes with the `automaticKeyboardNavigation` setting. To disable it do the following:

1. **File** -> **Preferences** -> **Settings** (Ctrl+Comma)
2. Search for `automaticKeyboardNavigation`
3. Uncheck the checkbox
   [image: The setting]

Or add this to your `settings.json`

```
"workbench.list.automaticKeyboardNavigation": false,
```